# C++ How to get current logged-on user name which is Microsoft Account?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, window, windows-10-universal

In Windows 10 , user can use Microsoft Account to login , i know how to get offline user name but online user name can't.

How to get correct user name while user uses the Microsoft Account to login windows by C++ ?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: What's application you are developing?

Answer (score 1):

You can get "internet principal name" from NetUserGetInfo(...) function.
with level 24.

pseudo code is :

```
if(NetUserGetInfo(NULL, sAccountName, 24, (LPBYTE*)&pInfo24) == NERR_Success)
{
    sPrincipalName = pInfo24->usri24_internet_principal_name;
}
```